# Advanced counting in Kafka Streams

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, reduce

I'd like to determine the number of assigned companies to a category. The (simplified) data structure of the input topic looks something like this:

```
Key: 3298440
Value: {"company_id": 5678, "category_id": 9876}

Key: 4367848
Value: {"company_id": 35383, "category_id": 9876}

[...]
```

So, like in this example, I'd like to count the different companies for the category 9876.

My idea was to group by `category_id` (the new key) and in- or decrease the count (via `reduce()`) as the value.

So in principle, I'm only interested in inserts and deletes (tombstones) for altering the count. My problem is, that updates will also produce a record and invalidate the count.

I believe I'm on the wrong track here. Is there any way to do it?

This is my incorrect java code, which also counts updates:

```
companyCategoriesKTable
                .groupBy(KeyValue::pair, Grouped.with(Serdes.String(), companyCategoriesSerde))
                .aggregate(
                        () -> new CompanyCount(0L, 0L), /* category_id, count */
                        (key, newValue, aggValue) -> {
                            aggValue.setCategoryId(newValue.getBrId());
                            aggValue.setCount(aggValue.getCount() + 1);
                            return aggValue;
                        },
                        (key, oldValue, aggValue) -> {
                            aggValue.setCategoryId(oldValue.getBrId());
                            aggValue.setCount(aggValue.getCount() - 1);
                            return aggValue;
                        },
                        Materialized.<String, CompanyCount, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as("CompanyCountStore").withKeySerde(Serdes.String()).withValueSerde(new JsonSerde<>(CompanyCount.class))
                )
                .toStream()
                .map((k, v) -> new KeyValue<>(v.getCategoryId(), v.getCount() > 0 ? 1L : -1L))
                .groupByKey(Grouped.with(Serdes.Long(), Serdes.Long()))
                .reduce(Long::sum)
                .toStream()
                .to("output-topic", Produced.with(Serdes.Long(), Serdes.Long()));
```

Comment: There's nothing in your data that tells you the operation, so how are you expected to count properly?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe Kafka knows if it's an insert, update or delete (key is new = insert -> call adder only; key is known and value is not null = update -> call adder + subtractor; key is known and value is null = deletion -> call subtractor only)

Comment: Sure, but you need to actually query the statestore to know if the key existed before for yourself to know its an update, regardless of the value null-ness. Or if you were gathering data from Debezium, for example, the operation type is always part of the record value